# Нестабильное время ответа от сервера. HighLoad

Tags: php, ubuntu, postgresql, nginx, cloudflare

У меня связка nginx + php-fpm + postgresql + redis.
Не могу понять почему ответ от моего сервера не стабилен при большой нагрузке.
У меня где-то около 1000 запросов в секунду.
в Cloudflare отключил все возможные Rate limiter.
Хочу заметить что по htop средняя загрузка сервера 6%
Не понимаю почему он не использует всю свою мощи чтобы обрабатывать больше и быстрее запросы.

[Скрин htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/key5Y.png)
[Скрин iotop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40mZF.jpg)

Мои конфиги:

Postgres

[image]

PHP-fpm:

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 4000
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 0
```

Nginx:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 12;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
worker_rlimit_nofile 150000;
events {
        worker_connections 8000;
        multi_accept on;
        use epoll;
}

http {
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_min_length 20;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log off;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

        include cloudflare;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
}
```

Вот скрин как выглядит "нестабильность":

[image]

Вывел в своем скрипте время его выполнения нормальное время его выполнения 0.02c

но вот бывает 0.2с 0.4с 0.7с

в нем 1 селект в базу всего.

По всем параметрам должно все быстро работать. запас еще есть. но не работает.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что с этим делать. Бьюсь неделю - безуспешно.

Хочу дополнить что если на сайт заходит уже до 300 человек то все начинает жутко висеть.

Comment: Узкое место где у вас? В базе?

Comment: я не думаю что оно узкое. база вроде бы все нормально обрабатывает, скорости записи и чтения на диск с головой хватает. думаете дело в базе?

Comment: я думаю, вам надо измерить и найти узкое место для начала, а потом уже что то решать

Comment: я ведь приложил скрин с iotop, нагрузка мизерная, 5-10% в пике

Comment: htop - это начальный этап, дальше нужно замерять времена ответа внутри скрипта от БД, профайлинг самой БД и многое другое.

Comment: Сколько памяти? Используются ли сессии? Мало информации, но скорее всего медленные запросы связаны с форканьем процессов PHP-FPM (используйте static вместо ondemand) и очисткой старых сессий. См [здесь](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/php/cleanup-php-sessions-like-a-pro)

Comment: Кстати насчёт сессий, если они до сих пор хранятся в файлах, то возможно стоит перенести их в какое-нибудь более быстрое хранилище, вроде Redis

Comment: памяти оперативной 64 гига. проц 6/12. ССД 1 ТБ. 
все отдыхает.
попробовал static, попробовал сессии в редис перенести - без толку(

Comment: Нужно смотреть куда уходит время для конкретного запроса. Сколько времени идет на запрос к БД, в частности, сколько на обработку всего в php (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script). Чтоб понимать, где затык.

Comment: стоит laravel. вот затык где-то в его boot судя по всему. потому что мой скрипт 30 мс обрабатывается и 1-2-3 с может до него где-то идти. но опять же не каждый раз. 1 из 10 может быть запросов таких. Микротаймом и проверял. именно с моим скриптом всегда все хорошо

Comment: В моменты, когда случаются медленные запросы, какое количество одновременных запросов обрабатывается?

Comment: одновременно всегда очень много запросов. + ещё очереди.

Comment: Много это сколько? Важно знать более менее точно. Также нужно знать сколько у вас потоков или процессов ( не знаю как там пхп устроено) которые могут собственно их исполнять. Если запросов пришло много, а собственно, процессоров мало, то это все может объяснить. Запросы ждут в очереди на исполнение. Если загрузка сервера при этом мала, то еще можно добавить екзекуторов

Comment: 1000-2000 в секунду зависит от кол-ва людей.
fpm процессов уже 2000 на статик выставил. ничего не помогает по сути. 
процессор отдыхает 6% нагрузка. ссд отдыхает до 5 % нагрузка. и я просто не знаю уже куда копать... может в самой убунту какие-то ограничения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Был перегружен redis.
Не стоило использовать keys.

Comment: Странно, тогда редис должен был бы быть виден в htop